# delete recursively number from linked list

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, struct, linked-list

hello guys i made a func which deleting from a linked list recursively according to the number you want to delete from the linked list. but after the removing if im trying to print the list its stack and there is a run-time error because after the removing there is just nothing in the place of the number. how can i complete the code ?

```
 struct node* delete_item(struct node* head, int num)
{
    if (head == NULL) { // Found the tail
        printf("not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (head->data == num) 
    { // Found one to delete
        head = head->next;
        free(head);
        printf("num founded");
        return head->next;
    }
    else 
    { // Just keep going
        head->next = delete_item(head->next, num);
        return head;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You freed what should be returned and dereferended the pointer pointing at what is freed. This is what is wrong.

You should introduce a buffer to store what should be returned.

```
struct node* delete_item(struct node* head, int num)
{
    if (head == NULL) { // Found the tail
        printf("not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (head->data == num) 
    { // Found one to delete
        struct node* next = head->next;
        free(head);
        printf("num founded");
        return next;
    }
    else 
    { // Just keep going
        head->next = delete_item(head->next, num);
        return head;
    }
}
```